# emulator-headless not found

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci

Hi I had a build script on travis that would install the android-sdk and launch an emulator in headless mode, it worked fine until a day ago when suddenly I get an error

```
bash: /home/travis/android-sdk/emulator/emulator-headless: No such file or directory
```

here is the build script, any ideas as to why emulator-headless disappeared?

https://gist.github.com/mandelmonkey/941ef6e64b0d83a1b7dc8e17848b70a8

Answer (score 11):

Since Emulator v29.2.11, `emulator-headless` is no longer present as a separate binary, but it has been merged to `emulator -no-window`.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

Answer (score 1):

I am having a very similar issue where the emulator -no-window flag does not work anymore since a couple of days. Something definitely broke.

Comment: I managed to get it working by calling just emulator and adding a -gpu off option, here is my build script

https://gist.github.com/mandelmonkey/90dbba77c2a5fffecf8e846bf631ded6

Comment: There was a separate issue (segfault / emulator crash) with the '-no-window' flag in certain environments they just resolved with 29.3.0 released to stable channel yesterday, it might have gotten you.

Comment: for my env I also had to set ```-gpu off```